# uncaught refference error: alertbox with value from a list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I m trying to get a alert if clicked on th button where the first value in the list is displayed. I m using the following code based on this [threat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24750623/select-a-row-from-html-table-and-send-values-onclick-of-a-button). In this threat they are using a table not a list. But i thought that that was not a problem... i think it is now. The code i m using is this.( The features are from a openlayer map):

```
<ul id ="table_overvieuw">
<#list features as feature>
  <li><b>Type: ${type.name}</b> (id: <em>${feature.fid}</em>):
  <ul>
  <#list feature.attributes as attribute>
    <#if !attribute.isGeometry>
      <li><b>${attribute.name}</b></li>
      ${attribute.value}
    </#if>
  </#list>
  <br><br>
 <input type="button" name="geef slijpplaten info" class="ok" value="OK" onclick="myFunction()" />
  </ul>
  </li>
</#list>
</ul>
<script type="text/javascript">
function highlight(e) {
    if (selected[0]) selected[0].className = '';
    e.target.parentNode.className = 'selected';
}

var table = document.getElementById('table_overvieuw'),
    selected = table.getElementsByClassName('selected');
table.onclick = highlight;

function myFunction(){

    alert($("li.selected li:first" ).html());
}

</script>
```

The error i m getting in the console is : *Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined*. The $ is from this piece of code:

```
 alert($("li.selected li:first" ).html());
```

can somebody give me a helping hand?

Comment: `$('...')` is the jquery selector, did you include jquery in your html page?

Comment: Thanks! i didnt realise i was using it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use jquery you must to have it on you page.
Use CDN (http://jquery.com/download/#using-jquery-with-a-cdn).
Also you can install it with bower (bower install jquery) and link it on page:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
...
</head>
...
</html>
```

Comment: or you can use <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>. No need for install

Answer (score 0):

If the list box is being properly formed then try the code below inside the alert box:-

```
$('ul#table_overview li:first').text()
```

Comment: where do i need to place this exactly?

Comment: function myFunction(){

    alert($("li.selected li:first" ).html());
}
Replace the existing code with the code above

Comment: can you explain to me what it does? because i filled it in(with a alert for the $) and the alert has a responce with nothing in it