# Select a row (highlight) from html table and send values onclick of a button

Tags: javascript, html, css

Highlight is not function in the web browser. What is the problem of this codes ? Basically, I want to do something highlighted the table row and then post the value of table row to another php page.

test.html

```
<html>
<head>
<link href="test.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="test.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<table id="table">
    <tr>
        <td>1 Ferrari F138</td>
        <td>1 000€</td>
        <td>1 200€</td>
        <td>Model monopostu stajne Scuderia Ferrari pre sezónu 2013</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>F138</td>
        <td>Klik pre detaily</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2 Ferrari F138</td>
        <td>1 000€</td>
        <td>1 200€</td>
        <td>Model monopostu stajne Scuderia Ferrari pre sezónu 2013</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>F138</td>
        <td>Klik pre detaily</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3 Ferrari F138</td>
        <td>1 000€</td>
        <td>1 200€</td>
        <td>Model monopostu stajne Scuderia Ferrari pre sezónu 2013</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>F138</td>
        <td>Klik pre detaily</td>
    </tr>
</table>

    <input type="button" id="tst" value="OK" onclick="fnselect()" />
</body>
</html>
```

test.js

```
function highlight(e) {
    if (selected[0]) selected[0].className = '';
    e.target.parentNode.className = 'selected';

}

var table = document.getElementById('table'),
    selected = table.getElementsByClassName('selected');
table.onclick = highlight;

function fnselect(){
var $row=$(this).parent().find('td');
    var clickeedID=$row.eq(0).text();
   // alert(clickeedID);
}

$("#tst").click(function(){
    var value =$(".selected td:first").html();
    value = value || "No row Selected";
    alert(value);
});
```

test. css

```
td {border: 1px #DDD solid; padding: 5px; cursor: pointer;}

.selected {
    background-color: brown;
    color: #FFF;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24750623/select-a-row-from-html-table-and-send-values-onclick-of-a-button You can check this question

Comment: yup, i had checked, but the highlight function is not perform, i don't know what is the problem error from these code.

Comment: Seems to be working fine from just pasting your code into jsfiddle. You may not be including the css path correctly, or may be getting another error.

Comment: You have a number of problems with your code. You should use console.log in your JavaScript to debug what is going wrong. For instance, start with seeing if things actually get selected or clicked by using console.log. Also, just with a couple console.logs, I noticed that you haven't even included a jquery script, so you can't use jquery (that $-sign). Try googling around for some tutorials on the basics. Maybe W3Schools, search for onclick.

Comment: Ah, yes - if you're not including jQuery then your code will not work, as it appears to be jQuery dependant. Here is my working sample: https://jsfiddle.net/xxd0zraw/

Comment: Okay. Noted, tyvm guys... jQuery script problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need fnselect() function

modify your js as :

```
window.onload = function () {
    function highlight(e) {
        if (selected[0]) selected[0].className = '';
        e.target.parentNode.className = 'selected';    
    }    
    var table = document.getElementById('table'),
        selected = table.getElementsByClassName('selected');
    table.onclick = highlight;

        $("#tst").click(function () {
        var value = $(".selected td:first").html();
        value = value || "No row Selected";
        alert(value);
    });
};
```

also add jquery in your html before the other test.js in head:

and finally
make one of the row  default selected.